# error `Cannot access offset of type string on string`

Tags: php, laravel, request, laravel-8, roles

**LARAVEL 8**

**error: Cannot access offset of type string on string**

```
$user = $userAction->run($request->all());

    if ($request->has('role')) {
        $user->assignRole($request->role['name']);
    }
```

the error is in this line:

```
           $user->assignRole($request->role['name']);
```

Comment: `$request->role` returns a `string`, not an array. Did you mean `$user->assignRole($request->role)` or `$user->assignRole($request->input('role'))`?

Comment: $user->assignRole($request->role

Comment: Tim Lewis
 o thanks $user->assignRole($request->input('role'))

Answer (score 0):

$request->role returns a string, not an array

**answer**

$user->assignRole($request->input('role'))